# JIT tracable PyTorch Tensor with meaningful properties

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

### The Scenario

I have a PyTorch module which outputs a tensor of shape `(batch_size, 3, 512, 7)`. The final dimension (7) is a tensor of meaningfully interpretable values which can be used in loss calculation.

I can access these values using slicing, and have successfully done so in the past like in the following examples

```py
foo = tensor[..., 0:1]
target_foo = target_tensor[..., 0:1]
some_loss_function(foo, target_foo)
```

or

```py
bar = tensor[..., 1:3]
target_bar = target_tensor[..., 1:3]
some_other_loss_function(bar, target_bar)
```

At first the code base was littered with these slicings. Since the slicing is not very human readable, unless one has specific knowledge of the how the network internally works, I have instead created my own tensor class which defines the various features neatly.

```py
class MyTensor(torch.Tensor):

    @property
    def foo(self):
        return self[..., 0:1]

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self[..., 1:3]
```

At some point in the model I have a module which wraps a resulting tensor in `MyTensor` during the fowrard pass

```py
class MyModule(torch.nn.Module):

    def forward(self, x: torch.Tensor) -> MyTensor:
        # do something to x
        x = x * 2  # this is purely exemplary, might be some network layers
        return MyTensor(x)
```

In a corresponding loss module I can now simply write

```py
class MyLoss(torch.nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.foo_loss_function: callable  # some arbitrary loss function for foo
        self.bar_loss_function: callable  # some arbitrary loss function for bar

    def forward(self, x: MyTensor, target: MyTensor):
        foo_loss = self.foo_loss_function(x.foo, target.foo)
        bar_loss = self.bar_loss_function(x.bar, target.bar)
        return foo_loss + bar_loss
```

To me this is *much* more readable, and I would like to keep it this way if possible.

### The problem

When now tracing the model containing a module like `MyModule` above, I get the following warning:

```py
import torch
model = MyModule()
some_input = torch.rand((32, 3, 512, 7))
torch.jit.trace(model, some_input)
```

> TracerWarning: torch.Tensor results are registered as constants in the trace.
> You can safely ignore this warning if you use this function to create tensors
> out of constant variables that would be the same every time you call this
> function. In any other case, this might cause the trace to be incorrect.
> return MyTensor(x)

I understand why I'm getting this warning, the tracer apparently has no knowledge of how to dynamically assign values from the original tensor `x` to this `MyTensor` tensor. In principle, no operation should even be necessary since all I'm doing is trying to add some ease of use accessability properties to an existing tensor, but apparently the tracer doesn't know what to do here.

Has anyone run into an issue similar to this? Is there a way to keep the readability of using an approach like the one described above using `MyTensor` whilst still being able to trace the model? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: this solution works if the class is a subclass of NamedTuple because the JIT tracer doesn't know how to handle return types other than `torch.Tensor` `tuple` `list` or `dict` (or the deprecated `torch.Variable`) in `torch.nn.Module`'s `forward` method.

I've been thinking about this for a while and I think the best solution is simply to wrap the original tensor in some kind of wrapper class, then have the original tensor be accessible via a `tensor_wrapper.tensor` attribute. I.e. something like this:

```py
import typing

import torch

class TensorWrapper(typing.NamedTuple):
    tensor: torch.Tensor

    @property
    def foo(self) -> torch.Tensor:
        return self.tensor[..., 0:1]

    ...  # other methods
```

Only downside is that one can no longer directly access the tensor, but I suppose it's better practice anyway since turning a `torch.Tensor` into a subclassed tensor like `MyTensor` probably copies memory (including the graph) and incurs extra overhead.